# How to send streaming from Android via WiFi base on VLC or RTSP?

Tags: android, audio-streaming, vlc, android-wifi, rtsp

I am new for this.

I want to develop an application that it can streaming music for `SD card` to another device via WiFi.

There has many protocol for streaming , like RTP ,RTCP and RTSP.

But I don't know how to begin for streaming...

**Ideal is like the following:**

**1.** `Android Phone-A` turn on the `Hotspot(Wireless Access Point mode)` , and the client will connect to this `Android Phone-A`.

**2.** After client to this `Android Phone-A`, `Android Phone-A` can choose the `MP3 music file`, and live-streaming to this client via WiFi (`not WiFi Direct`).

**3.** And the client will play the music from `Android Phone-A`.

**So , what I have to develop is A streaming Server.**

**Question:**

**1.** Should I use `RTSP server` on Android for doing streaming to client via WiFi ? 
or it is better for using VLC on Android ?

**2.** Does there has Android api for VLC can be develop on Android ?

**3.** How to encode and send the music streaming from `Wireless Access Point` to `client` ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does somebody can help me ?

Answer (score 2):

for your questions,

1. You can use VLC to make things easier, but you can write your own server to stream via RTP if you would
2. You can check [libVLC](https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC/) for VLC API
3. You would use `android.net.rtp.AudioCodec` for encoding and decoding and stream it using `android.net.rtp.AudioStream`. For more details, you can consult [android documentation on RTP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/rtp/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a pure Java library [libstreaming](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming). With it, you easily create an RTSP server. It is licensed under GPL.